# TypeError: Handlebars.templates is undefined

Tags: undefined, handlebars.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm working with `yeoman`, `gruntjs` and `handlebars.js`, but my template don't load anymore with the following error in firebug:

```js
TypeError: Handlebars.templates is undefined
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.templates['cheatsheet.hbs'];
```

## Handlebars.JS

In my `package.json`, I got:

```js
"grunt-contrib-handlebars": "~0.5.9" // previously used ~0.5.8
```

## Gruntjs tasks

### Task: `handlebars`

I'm compiling `.hbs` to `.hbs.js` files:

```js
handlebars: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            namespace: 'JST'
        },
        files: {
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/cheatsheet.hbs.js':
            [ '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/{,*/}*.hbs'] ,
        }
    }
},
```

### Task: `watch`

I added the following in the `watch` section:

```js
watch: {
    // recompile handlebars' templates when they change
    // @see: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Handlebars-integration
    handlebarsCompile: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/{,*/}*.hbs'],
        tasks: ['handlebars:compile']
    },
    handlebarsReload: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.hbs.js'],
        tasks: ['livereload']
    },
```

### Tasks: `grunt server` and `grunt build`

I added the following entry to both task:

```js
    'handlebars:compile',
```

## HTML file

I'm importing handlebars, the template and the script to inflate it:

```html
<script src="components/handlebars.js/dist/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/cheatsheet.hbs.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

### Compiled template: `cheatsheet.hbs.js`

In the top lines, I got this:

```js
this["JST"]["app/templates/cheatsheet.hbs"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
```

### Template inflater: `main.js`

To inflate my compiled template I'm using this:

```js
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.templates['cheatsheet.hbs'];
```

## Question

So what's the matter here `Handlebars.templates` array? Why is not created? How to create it?

### More info

I created a [gist to hold the full `Gruntfile.js` and `cheatsheet.hbs.js`](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/5803801).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the [section on precompiler usage](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#usage-1):

> If using the precompiler's normal mode, the resulting templates will
>   be stored to the Handlebars.templates object using the relative
>   template name sans the extension. These templates may be executed in
>   the same manner as templates.

I went on to debug the compiled template.

## Debugging

## Manual compilation

As I installed `handlebars` global, I can run compile templates manually. This wasn't enough, and I had to update the live file:

```
handlebars ./app/templates/cheatsheet.hbs -f ./app/scripts/cheatsheet.hbs.js # compile
cp ./app/scripts/cheatsheet.hbs.js ./.tmp/scripts/cheatsheet.hbs.js # update .tmp's template
```

## Comparing with what `grunt` outputs

I saw that compiled template where different, the template reference doesn't occur in the same variable.

### Manually compiled vs. Grunt compiled

```js
- (function() {
-    var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
- templates['cheatsheet.hbs'] = template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
+ this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};
+ 
+ this["JST"]["cheatsheet.hbs"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
```

So I went to my task and saw

```
namespace: 'CHSH.Templates'
```

So I read the [doc about namespace](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars#namespace), and I wasn't using the right namespace in `main.js`

## Solution

### Step #1: Updating package

First globally:

```
sudo npm update handlebars -g
```

Then locally

```
bower update
```

I got some message about handlebars, but doesn't block:

> Please note that
>        requires handlebars.js ~1.0.11
>
> Resolved to handlebars.js v1.0.0, which matches the requirement
>   defined in the project's component.json. Conflicts may occur.

### Step #2: Update `Gruntfile.js`

1. I set the namespace to `CHSH.Templates` (cf. [doc about namespace](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars#namespace)) ;
2. I updated the `files` option to compile the `*.hbs` template from the `app/templates` directory to the `.tmp/scripts/` and
   `app/scripts` directories;

```js
handlebars: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            namespace: 'CHSH.Templates'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates',
            src: '*.hbs',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/',
            ext: '.hbs.js'
        },
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates',
            src: '*.hbs',
            dest: '.tmp/scripts/',
            ext: '.hbs.js'
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also edited to `watch` task to look after `scripts/{,*/}*.js`.

### Step #3: Update `main.js`

Then I updated the namespace to match what I declared in my `Gruntfile.js`

```diff
-    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.templates['cheatsheet.hbs'];
+    var compiledTemplate = CHSH.Templates['app/templates/cheatsheet.hbs'];
```